# What other bindings are there except for pylinkgrammar

Tags: python, link-grammar

I am trying to using link-grammar within python.
However, it appears that there is a bug in the current version.

What other bindings/solutions are there to integrate link-grammar within python?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the specific use case for link-grammar and where it falls short. We might either be able to show you a fix or point you to a better alternative

Comment: I pass sentences from a csv file to link-grammar to verify if the sentences are valid. my implementation is basically a for loop going through the csv... and unfortunately, after 20-30 iterations, the pylinkgrammar object appears to die from a memory leak or such... all sentences including valid sentences (actualy sentences, that pass validation on the command line version of link-grammar) fail ..

Answer (score 0):

This is an old unanswered question, so here is a summary for people that encounter it.

The current Link-Grammar (5.4.4) already includes Python bindings (for both Python 2 & 3).  Most of the *nix distributions include ready packages (either in their main link-grammar package or in a separate package for the Python bindings).

The source code repository of link-grammar (including its Python bindings) is on [GitHub](https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar), and the directory [bindings/python-examples](https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar/tree/master/bindings/python-examples) includes demo programs (see there example.py, sentence-check.py and tests.py).

The package is actively developed and maintained, including its Python bindings. If you encounter a bug or or have a question you can open an issue on its GitHub site.